# Determine duplicates/pairs in an array in C++

Tags: c++

I have been doing this problem for 2 days now, and I still can't figure out how to do this properly.

In this program, I have to input the number of sticks available (let's say 5). Then, the user will be asked to input the lengths of each stick (space-separated integer). Let's say the lengths of each stick respectively are [4, 4, 3, 3, 4]. Now, I have to determine if there are pairs (2 sticks of same length). In this case, we have 2 (4,4 and 3,3). Since there are 2 pairs, we can create a canvas (a canvas has a total of 2 pairs of sticks as the frame). Now, I don't know exactly how to determine how many "pairs" there are in an array. I would like to ask for your help and guidance. Just note that I am a beginner. I might not understand complex processes. So, if there is a simple (or something that a beginner can understand) way to do it, it would be great. It's just that I don't want to put something in my code that I don't fully comprehend. Thank you!

Attached here is the link to the problem itself.
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/127/B

Here is my code (without the process that determines the number of pairs)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#define MAX 100

int lookForPairs(int numberOfSticks);

int main(void){
    int numberOfSticks = 0, maxNumOfFrames = 0;

    std::cin >> numberOfSticks;
    maxNumOfFrames = lookForPairs(numberOfSticks);
    std::cout << maxNumOfFrames << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int lookForPairs(int numberOfSticks){
    int lengths[MAX], pairs = 0, count = 0, canvas = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfSticks; i++){
        std::cin >> lengths[i];
    }
    pairs = floor(count/2);
    canvas = floor(pairs/2);
    return count;
}
```

I tried doing it like this, but it was flawed. It wouldn't work when there were 3 or more integers of the same number (for ex. [4, 4, 3, 4, 2] or [5. 5. 5. 5. 6]). On the first array, the count would be 6 when it should only be 3 since there are only three 4s.

```
 for(int i=0; i<numberOfSticks; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<numberOfSticks; j++){
            if (lengths[i] == lengths[j] && i!=j)
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorting the list is probably the first step to take

Comment: or use a `std::unordered_map` to count occurences

Comment: When you divide two integers, the result is an integer. All `floor` does to the result is to pointlessly convert it to a floating point number while possibly introducing a rounding error.

Comment: The first step is actually to use std::vector instead of "C" style arrays, that opens up most of the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm library for you to use. And the map is good choice to use for counting.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Agree about the vector, though actually most the algorithm library is usable with arrays, too, as one could use `array + beginOffset` and `array + endOffset` as the begin and end iterators (just for completeness..).

Comment: @Aconcague or `std::begin(array)` and `std::end(array)` which actually works with both

Comment: @Aconcagua I know that "C" style arrays can be used but still I always update to std::vector (or std::array) when moving to standard library algorithms (sometime I use std::begin/std::end). This to keep code style consistent and so I can refer to online examples when needed.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Well, if in control of the data. I wouldn't *copy* data received from e.g. 3rd party (C library used?) into just for the principle ;) But then maybe [ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) comes into place (need to get use to its existence yet…)?

Comment: @Aconcagua Agree a solution should not copy data if it doesn't have too. For strings there is string_view (pre C++20). I sometimes try ranges at home (stuck at C++17 at work for now), and yes they are nice. I really like range based for loops in combination with views (and their lazy evaluation). "No more raw loops" ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer *'No more raw loops'* – haha... The only case I met *'always'* and *'never'* working is in *'they don't work anywhere else'* ;) The fond I am of ranged based loops myself, too, I can think up just too many use cases they aren't suitable – at least not with extra work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing all the lengths and then comparing them, count how many there are of each length directly.

These values are known to be positive and at most 100, so you can use an `int[100]` array for this as well:

```
int counts[MAX] = {}; // Initialize array to all zeros.

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSticks; i++) {
    int length = 0;
    std::cin >> length;
    counts[length-1] += 1; // Adjust for zero-based indexing.
}
```

Then count them:

```
int pairs = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    pairs += counts[i] / 2;
}
```

and then you have the answer:

```
return pairs;
```

Comment: When I input [5, 5, 4, 4,1] = 2 (correct)
but when I input [4, 4, 4, 5, 4] = 1 (should be 2)
and [3, 3, 2, 5, 6] = 0 (should be 1)

Comment: @JobEnriquez Cannot [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/5GreGdf7E)! There must have gone wrong something else at another place.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vAQNWwKg

Comment: Range of `for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSticks; i++){ pairs += counts[i] / 2; }` is wrong, `numberOfSticks` should be `MAX` (or `for (auto count : counts) { pairs += count / 2; }`

Comment: @JobEnriquez Did you remember to input the number of lengths first?

Comment: May I ask what these parameters are for? @Aconcagua
int const* lengths, size_t numberOfSticks

Comment: The number of lengths im going to input (number of sticks)?@molbdnilo

Comment: @JobEnriquez They serve to forward the concrete test data into the functions as I operate on static test data stored in arrays (don't want to type in manually – and couldn't on demonstration site anyway). Note that Jarod42 in the meanwhile discovered why you *can* indeed get bad output, but then your lengths need to be larger than the number of inputs (the case in your last example, but there's no pair for 6 anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension to [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74219889/1312382): You can even count all pairs in one single iteration:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSticks; ++i)
{
    if(std::cin >> length) // catch invalid input!
    {
        pairs += flags[length] == 1; // add a pair if there is already a stick
        flags[length] ^= 1;          // toggle between 0 and 1...
    }
    else
    {
        // some appropriate error handling
    }
}
```

Note that I skipped subtracting 1 from the length – which requires the array being one larger in length (but now it can be of smallest type available, i.e. `char`), while index 0 just serves as an unused sentinel. This variant would even allow to use bitmaps for storing the flags, though questionable if, with a maximum length that small, all this bit fiddling would be worth it…

Comment: Or, `pairs += !(flags[length] ^= 1);`, of course ;-)

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh, yes… But I fear that would overstrain the QA, mine is already complicated enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of occurrences using a map. It seems that you are not allowed to use a standard map. Since the size of a stick is limited to 100, according to the link you provided, you can use an array, `m` of 101 items (stick's minimum size is 1, maximum size is 100). The element index is the size of the stick. The element value is the number of sticks. That is, `m[a[i]]` is the number of sticks of size `a[i]`. [Demo](https://ideone.com/NIldHt).

```
#define MAX 100

int n = 7;
int a[MAX] = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,3 };

int m[MAX + 1]; // maps stick len to number of sticks

void count()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    m[a[i]]++;
}

int main()
{
  count();
  for (int i = 1; i < MAX + 1; ++i)
    if (m[i])
      std::cout << i << "->" << m[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't visit the demo. Btw, what does [MAX + 1] do? increases the max value by 1 (101)?

Comment: @JobEnriquez Indeed it does. Like my answer this one skips shifting the one-based length into the range of zero-based indices – thus a stick length of 100 would be outside the valid range of an array of length 100, which only provides indices in the range of [0; 99]. Actually it might be meaningful do define two separate maxima – one considering maximum number of *input*, the other one the maximal stick length (here they are the same; actually we could simply have `int a[] = { ... }; int const n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);`, though, for not wasting surplus memory, then maximum input *would* be 7).

Comment: (1) The link works fine for me. (2) I assumed the data is read into `a`, as suggested by requirements. (3) According to requirements `1 <= a[i] <= 100`. If you have an array of size 100, the first index is 0 and the last index is 99, not 100. Therefore we must increase the `m` array size by 1, otherwise index 100 will be out of bounds. The element at index 0 is left unused, but that’s not a problem. (4) Instead of storing the input data in `a` you can use it as soon as you read it from console. (5) `n=7` and `a[MAX] =...` are just test examples. You must read them from console.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is counting forward from the very beginning each time, making you overcount the items in your array. Count forward from `i` , not zero.

```
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfSticks; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j<numberOfSticks; j++) { // count forward from i (not zero)
            if (lengths[i] == lengths[j] && i!=j) 
            { // enclosing your blocks in curly braces , even if only one line, is easier to read
                count++; // you'll want to store this value somewhere along with the 'length'. perhaps a map?
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: why start at `j=i` and `&& i!=j` ? Its a rather clumsy way of saying "start the loop at i but do nothing in the first iteration" vs "start at i+1"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because both loops go up the end... (they should have the first go 1 less) But anyway, how does this helps OP??

Comment: @Déjàvu "how does this helps OP??" its a comment directed at this answer not at OP. both loops can go up the end even if the inner one starts at `j = i+1`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It was re. "i!=j",  they  could do `i<numberOfSticks-1` in the 1st loop instead (and start from i+1 at the beginning in the 2nd loop) And, of course the "how does this help OP" was about this answer, not your comment :)

Comment: The other way round appears more convenient to me anyway: `for(i = 1; i < end; ++i) { for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) { ... } }` as it appears to be irrelevant if the triangle above or below the diagonal is the reference...

Comment: That fixes OP's loop, but that doesn't help solve the problem. The way your loops work, it will use a length more than once. For instance `2,2,2,2` has 2 pairs only. Your loops would render 6 pairs...